# Customize menu item of material ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `<select>` element of material ui, in which I'm looping the `menuItem` element.

Find the sample in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-sky-91j6w?file=/src/App.js)

I tried changing the background color of each of the menuitem, but still got a padding on top and bottom. Either I need to remove the padding or I need to change the backgroundColor of the whole list.

[image]

What I want to achieve is to change the color of the generated `muiPaper-root` class.

As this is not in the root DOM node, I'm not able to override css.

I tried using custom class, but it can only be applied to `menuItem` which is the child of parent `paperroot`.

In code `menuItem` is the immediate child of `select` which is in the root DOM node.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: in the menu list, you can see a padding on top and bottom, either I need to remove that one or need to change the color of entire paper root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that padding is coming from the `.MuiList-padding` which is the default padding in the `Menu`. Use the `MenuProps` prop to pass the props down to `Menu`. Then target the `list` class using `classes` property.

```
<Select
  MenuProps={{ classes: { list: classes.list } }}
  id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
  value={selectedOne}>
  {myList.map((ele, index) => (
    <MenuItem key={ele} value={ele} style={{ background: "grey" }}>
      {ele}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  list:{
    padding:0
  }
}));
```

Here is the working demo:
[image: Edit pedantic-ellis-y3buk]