# MUI Autocomplete change MenuItem padding (height)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I change padding (height) for each individual item (`MenuItem`) within the list of options

This does not work:

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <MenuItem
       {...props}
       key={option.id}
       sx={{ paddinTop: '20px', paddingBottom: '20px' }}>
           {option.userName}
       </MenuItem>
   )}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize menu item of material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065879/customize-menu-item-of-material-ui)

Comment: @Zak not really. The question is about padding on the Paper component that displays the list of items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [.MuiMenuItem-root](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu-item/#MenuItem-css-root) css class name.

example:

```js
<Autocomplete
  ...
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <MenuItem
       {...props}
       key={option.id}
       sx={{ '&.MuiMenuItem-root': { py: 20 } }}>
           {option.userName}
       </MenuItem>
   )}
  ...
/>
```